# If one ate milchig bread, how long is one milchig

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, dairy, yoreh-deah

If a Jew ate milchig bread, how long do they have to wait before they can eat fleishig again? The reason I ask is because in general if you drink milk as long as you wash your mouth you can pretty much eat right after. But if the milchig is part of a food which takes time to digest like bread, is one milchig for longer and therefor how long would one have to wait before meat products?

Comment: Kirk, have you ever studied Rav Melamed's Pnenei Halacha? He's the Rosh Yeshiva of possibly the leading Religious Zionist yeshiva, and the entire series is available online in English (and several other languages) for free. Many of the (very good) questions you ask on this site are answered there. If you would like to study it with a chavruta, that could be arranged. The site here: https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/

Comment: You seem to have a keen interest in halacha (as do I), the best way to level up is to set aside a block of time  every day (whether it's 5 minutes or 3 hours) and study by yourself or with a partner.

Comment: The Halacha Yomit page (created by students of former Sephardic Chief Rabbi Ovadia Yosef) is also very good for a 5 minute daily session, and usually brings both Sephardic and Ashkenazi positions. You can bookmark it on your phone and read it while you eat breakfast, for example: https://halachayomit.co.il/en/default.aspx

Comment: Milchik bread is no worse than cheese which is no different than milk unless it's hard cheese, which doesn't apply to milchik bread

Comment: Is milchig bread even allowed? https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.36a.11

Comment: @Shababnik with a distinct shape or in small batches, yes: https://halachayomit.co.il/en/Default.aspx?HalachaID=5027

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shulchan Aruch YD [89:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Yoreh_De%27ah.89.3) writes:

If one ate a tavshil of dairy one can eat meat afterwards as long as one washes out one's mouth.

Some people are machmir and have the custom to wait half an hour before eating meat again.

Comment: Note that "hard cheese" may have a different waiting time.